# Sequence Alignment of two Strings

Tags: java, performance, algorithm, strings, array

I have some code which aligns the sequence of two strings, I am doing numbers just for my implementation.

I was wondering whether there are any performance enhancements I could make as the code itself is \$O(n^2)\$ which isn't ideal in terms of scalability, here's the code:

```
        int[] goal = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14,15, 0};
        int[] test = {1, 5, 9, 11, 2, 10, 0, 6, 8, 14, 15, 12, 7, 4, 3, 13};
        int gap = 1;
        // The penalties to apply
        int substitution = 1, match = 0;

        int[][] opt = new int[goal.length + 1][goal.length + 1];

        // First of all, compute insertions and deletions at 1st row/column
        for (int i = 1; i <= goal.length; i++) {
            opt[i][0] = opt[i - 1][0] + gap;
        }
        for (int j = 1; j <= test.length; j++) {
            opt[0][j] = opt[0][j - 1] + gap;
        }

        for (int i = 1; i <= goal.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j <= test.length; j++) {
                int scoreDiag = opt[i - 1][j - 1] + (goal[i - 1] == test[j - 1] ? match : substitution); // different symbol
                int scoreLeft = opt[i][j - 1] + gap; // insertion
                int scoreUp = opt[i - 1][j] + gap; // deletion
                // we take the minimum
                opt[i][j] = Math.min(Math.min(scoreDiag, scoreLeft), scoreUp);
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= goal.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= test.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(opt[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
```

The value that I actually need from the code is `opt[goal.length][test.length]`

Comment: That looks like a variant of the Levenshtein algorithm. If so you can't reduce the n^2 time complexity but you can reduce your memory usage because you just need the previous line to compute the next.

Comment: Just need the previous line to computer the next? @永劫回帰

Comment: In fact, you need both the previous and the current line as can be seen here `opt[i][j - 1] + gap`,  `opt[i - 1][j] + gap`, `opt[i - 1][j - 1] + (goal[i - 1] == test[j - 1] ? match : substitution)`. You never need to go more than 1 line backward.

Answer (score 3):

One general way to speed up dynamic algorithms is the "[Method of Four Russians](http://cs.au.dk/~cstorm/courses/AiBS_e12/papers/Gusfield97_FourRussians.pdf)" - \$O(\frac{n^2}{\log n})\$. But to implement this method you should use limited alphabet (not like numbers in your implementation).

Although theoretically this method looks awesome, practically the size of a lookup table is growing fast (\$O(3^{2t} \cdot \left|A \right| \cdot t)\$, where \$\left|A \right|\$ is the size of an alphabet, and \$t\$ is a block size). For example, in the case of DNA (4 letters alphabet) it can fit to the modern cash memory just in the case of \$t\$ equals to [3 (\$\sim0.1MB\$) or 4 (\$\sim10MB\$)](http://cs.au.dk/~cstorm/students/MyHoa_Dec2010.pdf).

Another way to optimize the pairwise alignment is to take advantage of an extended instruction set of modern CPUs ([SIMD extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions)). Up to now there are several such implementations of the Smith-Waterman algorithm ([1](https://academic.oup.com/bioinformatics/article/23/2/156/205631/Striped-Smith-Waterman-speeds-database-searches) or [2](https://bmcbioinformatics.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12859-016-0930-z)).